# RadGrid Column widths and date picker

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I'm using radgrid with auto generated columns. there is a date column (Rev Date) in the data source. When binding to the grid, the grid column structure and column widths become a mess because of this date column.

[image]

when i convert the date column (Rev Date) into an varchar and bind the column as a string then the grid binding works fine with column widths.

[image]

How does the datepicker affect the column widths and mess up the grid structure? its fine if i could remove the calendar control to make the column widths looks good. I really need to use the date column in grid in order to get column sorting to work

Comment: is this issue raised in All browser?

Comment: @JayeshGoyani yes.i checked with IE,firefox and chrome. i spotted another issue with this date column. it causes post back when i click on filter icon on columns and the filter options are not showing up it just causes a postback. all issues occurs only if i add this date column if it's a string column everything works fine.